# How does chainlink solve the oracle problem?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, oracles, external-api, chainlink

I've heard a lot about Chainlink recently -- how Synthetix, Aave and other top Defipulse projects are using them. How exactly does Chainlink solve the oracle problem from a technical perspective?

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! This question needs more focus and for an example of focus see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/201/how-does-oraclize-handle-the-tlsnotary-secret  That said, here is a technical explanation from Feb 2020 https://www.kaleido.io/blockchain-blog/how-chainlink-works-under-the-covers and it would be too long to write here.