# Is it possible to invalidate a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

How can I invalidate a smart contract that has already been deployed? I might want to do so because of business reasons, and maybe beneficial network effects.

Is it possible to invalidate a smart contract?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the contract has a function that calls `selfdestruct` (initial name `suicide`), the contract will remain on the blockchain.

Comment: `self-destruct` can it be called after doing some api calls to a remote server? I am not sure whether remote api calls in allowed in the smart-contract

Comment: There are no remote API calls in Ethereum. See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/301/131.You have to use a service like http://oraclize.it. You can call `selfdestruct` at any time, but you need to explicitly code it into the contract. Otherwise the contract will live forever

Comment: @TjadenHess thats a valid point, edit the answer and add your point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a `SUICIDE` call which will render the contract inoperable. Notably, calling a deleted account won't result in an error so you would want to also have the application check the state of the account.

In Solidity the `SUICIDE` EVM call is performed by the `selfdestruct` function.

Comment: @niksmac The yellow paper doesn't have "selfdestruct" – that is a solidity function. Not sure editing answer makes sense for a comment.