# Why do smart contract languages need to be deterministic?

Tags: contract-design, protocol

I read somewhere that smart contract languages need to be deterministic. Why?

Comment: Though the question is different, this answer covers what you're asking: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/334/52

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As reminded in the first comment from Richard, smart contracts have to be deterministic because each nodes of the network have to be able to find the same result given the same input for a contract method. Otherwise each node that executes the contract method to validate the transaction would end with different results and no consensus would be possible.

But why the smart contract language itself such as Solidity have to be deterministic? It doesn't have to be.

Solidity is deterministic because it's a convenient language well designed for its purpose, but the Lisk network for instance uses standard JavaScript which is not deterministic. That means that nothing can avoid the use of a method to generate a random value in Lisk smart contracts. Developers thus have to be very careful to avoid using non deterministic functions. Sometimes this can be tricky. Math.random() function is obvious,  but some other math methods can use roundings that won't always give the same result or some date functions as the new Date() which gives the current date and is thus non deterministic. As you can read in the [Lisk documentation](https://lisk.io/documentation?i=lisk-dapps-docs/README#determinism) developers are warned not to use this functions. But if you are not careful you can completely wreck your contract.

The power of Solidity and other deterministic languages is that developers don't even have to care about determinism because there is no non deterministic functions in the language.

Comment: How do blockchain platforms (ex. Lisk and Fabric) make sure if the code of the non deterministic language (ex. Javascript and Golang) is deterministic?
Or they don't check if the smart contract code is deterministic, then consensus just fails?

Comment: They use a type of sharding, where each contract runs on its own chain, so consensus on the state of that contract can fail without harming other  contracts. This cannot happen on Ethereum, since it would break network consensus

Comment: How does sharding work in this context? Is a contract deployed in one of blockchains? It sounds like the contract needs to reach consensus in that blockchain, so the contract code still needs to be deterministic.

Comment: hey @SatoshiNakanishi are you the brother of Satoshi Nakamoto

Comment: @Nicolas Massart The more fundamental question I have is what does it mean to say Solidity is deterministic? so solidity does not return error or exception? for a given input to a function in solidity, there is only one output?

Comment: @user1870400 Solidity is deterministic in the way that for any inputs, it will always return the same values. So if you execute the smart contract with data that were provided in the transaction that triggered the contract, given the block in which the transaction is mined and state of the blockchain at this moment, you will always have the same result.

Comment: @user1870400 Also it doesn't mean it won't throw an exception, but it means that this exception will always be the same. For instance, if the exception is to say that you don't have enough ETH on your account for transaction A in block n, this state is true at this point of the blockchain life even if you add ETH in the future and have enough ETH in block n+1. Verifying the result of the contract for TX A will always be done against data available at block n.

Comment: I can code random function from scratch in the smart contract itself without using any library and I don't see how solidity can prevent that?

Comment: @user1870400 can you? What would be your entropy source?

Comment: @user1870400 can you? What would be your entropy source?

Comment: @NicolasMassart Yes. you can take a look at here https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go

Comment: That's interesting, I don't get all as I don't know Go much, but for what I saw it involves a lot of divisions and it may be very expensive as an EVM program. So worth trying for the concept and see if it breaks things, but I don't really see any use in real life as your transaction wont be validated if two executions give different results and costs a different amount of gas. Not even sure it would compile in Solidity... but you can try to confirm.

Comment: @NicolasMassart you got it! And yes there isn't much other than a bunch of bitwise operations and it must compile in solidity if not there is a much bigger problem with solidity.

Comment: @NicolasMassart "I don't really see any use in real life as your transaction won't be validated if two executions give different results and costs a different amount of gas" You hit the nail here! and I agree with this statement since this is taken care of the consensus algorithm. In general, if execution results are different across clients its my understanding that the consensus algorithm is smart enough to take care of this scenario but now comes back the same question which is why care about determinism so much when we have consensus to guard against invalid ouputs?

Comment: @NicolasMassart EVM is really a toy VM and its a good thing that Ethereum is moving to a WebAssembly instruction set where programs can run on native speed. saying a language or a VM is deterministic is rather a huge claim that I suspect lot of experts in the field won't be willing to make. I am happy to hear any counter arguments!!

Comment: @user1870400 so maybe we should say "evm is aimed at running deterministic programs and help developers to easily achieve this goal." Or something like that.

Comment: @user1870400 please have a look at Julien Marchands answer about the go random function.

Answer (score 7):

The determinism prevent any fork in the network.
The same goes for Solidity which uses the EVM.

To complete @NicolasMassart 's answer and @user1870400 comment that proposes to generate random values based on a possible Solidity implementation of the Go code used for random number generation, based on https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rng.go you can notice that this code **doesn't rely on any random** at all but uses hard coded entropy.

If you try it twice without specifying entropy, you'll get the same predictable result.
To use this in a concrete use-case, you're supposed **to bring your own source of entropy**, i.e.: rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()) for example.

Hopefully inside the EVM, each **source of entropy generate the same value** for a single transaction across each node of the network, whether you use the timestamp (aka block.timestamp or now -- because it's the timestamp of the time the block was issue by **the single miner** of this block) or any other pseudo random value.

So even implementing this algorithm in a smart contract using Solidity will lead to a deterministic result.

Comment: How about using previous block hash as an entropy source during a fork? I understand the longest chain wins and in the end(after consensus) everyone will have same blockchain. But say during the fork where multiple chains are competing what if a function uses previous block hash as an entropy source? There is a point in time where I tend to think it is nondeterministic although the end result (after consensus) is the same.

Comment: If you use the previous block hash:
1. you have about 15 sec during which everyone know the randomness and can create transactions fitting their needs
2. a miner who's about to publish a block with a specific block hash can refrain from doing it if it generates a unpleasant randomness for him.

Comment: Sure I am not questioning the validity of the end result and I understand consensus is there to guard. But your response sounds like we are in an agreement that is we should be able to observe the random behaviour during the fork when a user invokes a transaction that calls the rand function which uses previous block hash as a seed implemented in the contract itself. Let me know if you disagree