# Can you interact with other blockchains' tokens by using an Ethereum smart-contract?

Tags: tokens, blockchain-interoperation

Let's say that a dev has a public and private key of an address on another blockchain. He wants to create a smart-contract that can interacts with these coins, for moving them, for selling them, etc.

Is that possible to do such a thing on Ethereum ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A contract [can't make API calls](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/301/why-cant-contracts-make-api-calls) or broadcast transactions, so it **cannot directly move any coins or assets on another blockchain.**  (All data in contracts are also public, so they cannot hold private keys securely.)

A contract can only **incentivize some entity to broadcast transactions on the other blockchain.**  For example, an Ethereum contract could contain assets such as ether or tokens, which it would release to someone when the contract receives proof that a transaction on the other blockchain has occurred.