# Can one create a system with cryptocurrency and fiat on same platform?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain

Is it possible to create a platform by writing smart contracts on the Ethereum blockchain in which anyone can transact using any cryptocurrency and/or fiat? Perhaps the fiat can be converted internally into ether.

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2739/how-would-stablecoins-work-on-ethereum

Comment: Thanks @eth , but that question didn't answer my question . Mine one is very simple from them. I just want to know a way using which we can convert the real money to ether internally. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only three ways for ether to be created: (1) during the genesis block, (2) at each block as part of the block reward, and (3) at each block as part of the uncle reward (potentially).

Everything else is a transfer of ether from one account to another. The exchange of fiat for ether necessarily must take place outside of the chain.

For this reason I would say that it is impossible to build a smart contract system that deals with fiat in a fully `trustless` way. In other words, there will always have to be some sort of outside (outside of the blockchain) confirmation that the fiat was received and the ether is being transferred as a result of that transfer.

Think about the genesis block. The system itself could not have confirmed the genesis block. The genesis block is a bootstrap. How could the system itself possibly know which accounts should be assigned how many initial ether?

Comment: Is there any Solidity function to convert fiat to Ether?  For example, your rent is $500/month.  ETH is too volatile to sign a rent contract.  So it would be nice to make a smart contract based on the fiat, even if payment is made in Ethereum.

Comment: @NealWalters No. There is no Solidity function to convert from Ether to Fiat. You are looking for an idea called an Oracle or a Peg or Stable Coin. If you search around for those words, you've find stuff to read which may help you better understand.

Answer (score 0):

you could check https://limepay.io ; Helping dapps users execute Ethereum transactions with credit card. It is not the exact thing you are asking for, but could be helpful if you have dapp running on ethereum.