# Can you make HTTP calls with Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I want to create a very close to random number generator for a smart contract which I would like to do HTTP calls to webservices to do. Is that able to be done with Solidity? I am just digging into the docs now and have yet to read any mention of it, thanks!

Comment: For random number generation see: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract

Comment: @eth How are people using http://www.oraclize.it/ to pass data to a contract?

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-an-ethereum-contract-get-data-from-a-website  Also, notice that the right sidebar changes depending on the question you're viewing and has Related links that might help