# Writing to IPFS directly from solidity contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ipfs

Does anyone know how to add a file to IPFS directly from a solidity contract?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-an-ethereum-contract-get-data-from-a-website

Answer (score 1):

This should not be possible without any external service.

Comment: Can you do it using a Oracle service like http://www.oraclize.it/. You can use this service to query urls and APIs:

`oraclize_query("URL", "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT")`

I know IPFS have a API that you can access but I dont know how to add files to it from solidity contracts?

Comment: Yes - but this is basically an external service. Perhaps you should describe what you want to do - but somehow directly adding a file to IPFS from a solidity contract sounds really wrong to me.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I want my smart contract to be able to monitor data from an API using the oraclize service and write this data then to IPFS instead of storing it on the blockchain....

Comment: If you are using an external service anyway - why not add to IPFS from there? Don't see this as a good fit in the contract - also will be really expensive ..

Comment: I didn't think of that, do you know of any good resources for looking into how to implement that?

Comment: @SimonMullaney you can use https://embark.status.im

Answer (score 1):

No. And why would you want to? Seems like it could be a huge security hole. Just call your contract from an application, wait for the receipt, and then upload the information to IPFS.